# Backtrace for osx core dump using lldb

Tags: macos, lldb

My kernel extension crash a several times so I want to get the correct backtrace (with function names) from the crash

Accroding to the article https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html
I wanted to use gdb for this, but it seems that GDB does not understand the dump

```
dhcp80-241:KernelDebugKit gburanov$ sudo gdb -c /PanicDumps/core-xnu-2050.48.12-10.41.20.195-39882f44
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824) (Wed Feb  6 22:51:23 UTC 2013)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".
Core file contained no thread-specific data
(gdb)
```

I heard that it is not possible by gdb, but lldb does not work as well

```
dhcp80-241:KernelDebugKit gburanov$ lldb
(lldb) target create -d -c /PanicDumps/core-xnu-2050.48.12-10.41.18.191-2c2bf92f /Volumes/KernelDebugKit/mach_kernel
Loading kernel debugging from /Volumes/KernelDebugKit/mach_kernel.dSYM/Contents/Resources/Python/mach_kernel.py
LLDB version LLDB-179.5
settings set target.process.python-os-plugin-path "/Volumes/KernelDebugKit/mach_kernel.dSYM/Contents/Resources/Python/lldbmacros/core/operating_system.py"
command script import "/Volumes/KernelDebugKit/mach_kernel.dSYM/Contents/Resources/Python/lldbmacros/xnu.py"
xnu debug macros loaded successfully. Run showlldbtypesummaries to enable type summaries.
error: Unable to find process plug-in for core file '/PanicDumps/core-xnu-2050.48.12-10.41.18.191-2c2bf92f'
(lldb)
```

What is the correct way to work with core dumps?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an lldb from Xcode 4.6 - I can't remember the state of core file support that version had -- and the kernel debug commands provided with the kenel dSYM aren't going to work with that lldb. You'll need to install Xcode 5.1 to get this to work.

The fact that gdb said it couldn't find a register context in the core file may indicate that you have a corrupt/truncated core file. The lldb in Xcode 5.1 will be a better check on that.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to install new Xcode and now I have different error message  **error: core file doesn't contain any LC_THREAD load commands, or the LC_THREAD architecture is not supported in this lldb
(lldb) **

Comment: Does it really mean my core files are all broken? I have 5-6 of them, created just yesterday! Is there a way to check the integrity of core dump?

Comment: Use `otool -hlv` on your core file.  You'll see thousands of load commands -- one for each memory region in your process when it core dumped.  You should see (usually at the end) some LC_THREAD load commands - multi-thread/core coredumps may have more than one.  This is the register state of the crashing thread - without this, lldb can't tell anything about the coredump beyond what binaries were in memory at the time.

Comment: I decided to write you a mail =)

Comment: I got this error message when core file did not have read permissions for others and it was owned by root wheel. Try changing it to give read permissions to all using chmod.